# How to set different colors area chart depending on value Vega Lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I want to create area chart in which area above y=0 will be one color anb below - another. I have a problem with setting conditional color in Vega-Lite. (I'm using guide from https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/condition.html)

```json
"color": {
      "condition": {
        "test": "datum['y'] < 0",
        "value": {
          "x1": 1,
          "y1": 1,
          "x2": 1,
          "y2": 0,
          "gradient": "linear",
          "stops": [
            {
              "offset": 0,
              "color": "white"
            },
            {
              "offset": 1,
              "color": "orange"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "value": {
       // otherValue
    }
```

Full code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/interactive-vega-lite-bar-chart-forked-b0hnh?file=/index.html

Comment: What is your expected outcome ?

Comment: @wahabmemon I want area above y=0 to be one color and below another

Answer (score 0):

The condition is not working on mark `area`. Tried the same for type `bar` or `point` and it worked. Still managed to get the gradient effect with colors red, white and orange. You can refer the below config or refer [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2021-03-29", "value": -10, "rValue": 0},
      {"date": "2021-03-28", "value": -20, "rValue": 0},
      {"date": "2021-03-27", "value": 20, "rValue": 0},
      {"date": "2021-03-26", "value": 40, "rValue": 0},
      {"date": "2021-03-25", "value": 35, "rValue": 0}
    ]
  },
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "mark": {"type": "area"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {"format": "%d/%m/%Y", "labelPadding": 10}
    },
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "fill": {
      "value": {
        "gradient": "linear",
        "stops": [
          {"offset": 0, "color": "red"},
          {"offset": 0.5, "color": "white"},
          {"offset": 1, "color": "orange"}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "config": {}
}
```

Also, I tried your mark `area` with a simple configuration and that didn't work. I have created a config having [bar](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABEyTrDsU5kMB3OjEOy+O0oeJJBDNZUMB1OOaRZQxgaVUN6fyQADxoIQ2U2ZBog4UcFQ0DlQ2SITDgkLIYISPM5ZTpdd0MyTSyoNkE2M0w2ePUkawzDAC84dVaTYtS4SkUVJEwUVFA3DzU0AG1QKZB9MaY0fgAmAA4AXwVltBAAIXW0MTEDo-QAYXPUfgBmJ+uQFYARB4BOAEY3lYAUQeO3+h3exwAYg8xK9wSsAOIPfi-b4A44ACRBAHZ0egAJIwrZ7AC6BxAyHUAGtjiZ1GM4LJ6uVZGQ0KAouyQAAzGhwQTKY4oJSYACeODgx1kiWS7jG0ViXISST03PcxRFNCgVIgaDVgg1IEESCY-P0rMEktQAAYlMbTYIAAoFFls1AAFj25NFXN5-MF6A2IvFVpAAEcGIEdJNnJLybzBIIufVZOUdHIuXlcsdlBMGAhKExDAAeQzWsazTy0uYgcmV0M1OCM2teoA) which works properly with condition but if the same is changed to [area](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABEyTrDsU5kMB3OjEOy+O0oeJJBDNZUMB1OOaRZQxgaVUN6fyQADxoIQ2U2ZBog4UcFQ0DlQ2SITDgkLIYISPM5ZTpdd0MyTSyoNkE2M0w2ePUkawzDAC84dVaTYtS4SkUVJEwUVFA3DzU0AG1QKZB9MaY0fgAmAA4AXwVltBAAIXW0MTEDo-QAYXPUfgBmJ+uQFYARB4BOAEY3lYAUQeO3+h3exwAYg8xK9wSsAOIPfi-b4A44ACRBAHZ0egAJIwrZ7AC6BxAyHUAGtjqZ8mM4LJ6uVZGQ0KAouyQAAzGhwQTKWljTAATxwcGOskSyXcY2isS5CSSem57mKSh0UCpEDQqsE6pAgiQTH5+lZgglqAADEojSbBAAFAostmoAAse3JIq5vP5gvQGw1YstIAAjgxAjpJs4JeTeYJBFz6rJyjo5Fy8rljsoJgwEJQmIYADyGK1jWaeY5MOYgckVkM1OCM2ueoA) than it does not work.

Comment: No. That's not behavor I'm looking for. 
I want area under x axis to be red, and above orange

Comment: Yes understood. But the area is not getting changed depending on the conditions. You mush have compared the bar and area config that i have attached in my answer. Both the behaviours are quite different

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to overlay a separate layer.

[image]

However I'm not sure how to color the bit before the first negative value.

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-IA)

Comment: Is there a solution to this? i.e the area is not drawing coloring correctly on the other layer based on the filter.


I'm currently facing this issue for my chart as well.